# AspNetUsers custom columns don't appear in intellisense

Tags: c#

Am trying to create a user database that I can modify to suit what my users will need to submit when registering for my service, I've created the database and am able to modify it and include whatever columns I want but I can't seem to access them in my c# code, the only fields that appear are those native to AspNetUsers, I've tried looking at similar questions but I can't seem to grasp the concepts specific to what I need, anyone that can help me get some clarity on this cause am a bit new to working with IdentityUser.

````
   

     //Registration/Login
        public class Identify : IIdentify
        {
            private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _manager;
        
            private readonly Mystery _jwtset;
            private readonly DataContext _personality;
        
            public Identify(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, Mystery jW, DataContext users)
            {
                _manager = userManager;
                _jwtset = jW;
                _personality = users;
            }
        
            public async Task<Authentication_result> RegisterAsync(string email, string password, string Username)
            {
                var exists = await _manager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        
        
                if (exists != null)
                {
                    return new Authentication_result
                    {
                        Errors = new[] { "User with this email already exists" }
                    };
                }
        
        
                var newPerson = new IdentityUser()
                {
                    Email = email,
                    UserName = Username
                };
        
        
                var Creation = await _manager.CreateAsync(newPerson, password);
        
                if (!Creation.Succeeded)
                {
                    return new Authentication_result
                    {
                        Errors = new[] { "Invalid user!" }
                    };
                }
        
                return Generate_Authentication_Result(newPerson);
            }
        
            public async Task<Authentication_result> LoginAsync(string email, string Password)
            {
        
                var exists = await _manager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        
        
                if (exists == null)
                {
                    return new Authentication_result
                    {
                        Errors = new[] { "User does not exists" }
                    };
                }
        
                var pass_validation = await _manager.CheckPasswordAsync(exists, Password);
        
                if (!pass_validation)
                {
                    return new Authentication_result
                    {
                        Errors = new[] { "f78wrvep034rf wrong" }
                    };
                }
        
                return Generate_Authentication_Result(exists);
            }
        
        
        
            private Authentication_result Generate_Authentication_Result(IdentityUser newPerson)
            {
                var Tokenhandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_jwtset.Secret);
                var TokenDescripter = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                   {
                               new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, newPerson.UserName),
                               new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                               new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, newPerson.Email),
                               new Claim("id",newPerson.Id)
        
                           }),
        
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2),
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                };
        
                var token = Tokenhandler.CreateToken(TokenDescripter);
        
                return new Authentication_result
                {
                    Success = true,
                    Token = Tokenhandler.WriteToken(token)
                };
            }
        
        }
        //Controller for the above
        
        public class IdentifyMe : Controller
        {
            private readonly IIdentify _identify;
        
        
            public IdentifyMe(IIdentify identifying)
            {
                _identify = identifying;
        
            }
        
            [HttpPost(Api_Routes.Identity.Register)]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserRegistration register)
            {
        
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(new Unauthenticated
                    {
                        Errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors.Select(xx => xx.ErrorMessage))
                    });
                }
        
        
                var authresponce = await _identify.RegisterAsync(register.Email, register.Password, register.User_Name);
        
                if (!authresponce.Success)
                {
                    return BadRequest(new Unauthenticated
                    {
                        Errors = authresponce.Errors
                    });
                }
                return Ok(new Authenticated
                {
                    Token = authresponce.Token
                });
            }
        
        
        
            [HttpPost(Api_Routes.Identity.Login)]
            public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync(User_login login)
            {
                var authresponce = await _identify.LoginAsync(login.email, login.Password);
        
                if (!authresponce.Success)
                {
                    return BadRequest(new Unauthenticated
                    {
                        Errors = authresponce.Errors
                    });
                }
                return Ok(new Authenticated
                {
                    Token = authresponce.Token
                });
            }
        
        
        }
        //Domain object, these are the values I would like to be able to access
        
        public class Users : IdentityUser
        {
            public string PreferredNet { get; set; }
            public int Inactive { get; set; }
            public int Active { get; set; }
            public int Max_Return { get; set; }
            public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        
        }
    //Other controller
    public ActionResult <IEnumerable<Time_dto>> Getitem(string usernum, int amt, string user, string server)
            {
                
              
                var Total = caller.Getusers();
//This is my attempt to acces the domain object, pitcture below[![Intelisense does not display fields in domain object][1]][1]
                var container=Total.Select(x=>x.)
                var totalin = _digital.Map<IEnumerable<User_dto>>(Total).Count(x => x.PreferredNet == user);
                var totalout= _digital.Map<IEnumerable<User_dto>>(Total).Count(x=>x.PreferredNet== server);
             
                int factor = 1;
                var HCD = caller.rates(factor, user, server);
             
                var result = shift;
                int retrive = caller.Total(amt, user, server, HCD);
                var serials = caller.cards(retrive);
                int differential = retrive > serials.Sum() ? retrive serials.Sum() : serials.Sum() - retrive;
                int number = serials.Count();
                IEnumerable<int> Real_cards=new List<int>();
    }
        ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEenG.png
````

Comment: The problem is only with intelisense?

Comment: Is your code as is in your question or separated into different namespaces in different .cs class files? Is there any example in your code trying to access the domain object?

Comment: I edited it out, wasn't working so didn't think to keep it there but the approach is standard, constructor, dependency inctect IdentityUser, call it in controller(different controller not the one in the posted question) and it brings the AspNetUser table columns except those those that were added from the domain object.

Comment: And yes it's separated into different namespaces.

Comment: Though now that I think about it let me add it in just to be safe.